# Stereo mix [PC audio + mic] without hearing mic?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, audio-streaming

{Windows10 and realtek drivers}

Hi, i've been searching all day for a solution to this: i already set up stereo mix, and i know how to recive audio from pc and mic, the problem is that when i configure this way [enabling listening mic trough the default audio device], i listen myself trough the headphones/speakers, whatever im using to listen.
Any solution to avoid this happen?

i already tried disabling the "pink input" and the mic from the speaker levels tab, but doesnt work, i still listening it...

[image]

Comment: Have you ever heard of devices like Virtual Audio Cable? This one isn't exactly the best, but what it does is create a dummy audio input/output you can play around with. For example, if you route your speaker out to the VAC, microphone out to the VAC, and put your VAC as the input audio for whatever you'd like to be recording, sending, etc. you would basically be combining your speaker and mic sound into one stream.

Comment: Yes, i already heard about that, but i dont want to use external sofware, i want to make it the most simple possible.

Comment: You're not going to get anything close to what you want without using software.

Comment: @Dispenser: What do you mean by Virtual Audio Cable? [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/)? [Virtual Audio Cable](http://virtualaudiocable.org/)? Anything else?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Probably this [Virtual Audio Cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the "Listen" settings in your Recording Device (Microphone)?

> - Right click on volume control (default next to clock)
> - Click "Recording Devices"
> - Right-click your device and click "Properties"
> - Navigate to "Listen" tab > Untick "Listen to this device"

[image: Listen Settings]

Comment: Its exactly what i did, the problem is that i dont want to hear myself through the speakers or headphones